# Which part of code must be inside foreach loop

Tags: php, class, barcode

The php code of barcode generator (which take from here http://www.barcodephp.com/en/userguide) looks like that.

I can't figure out which part must be inside foreach loop to generate multiple barcodes from array? `$code->parse('1'); // Text` this line gets 1 value - in this case number 1 and generates barcode. I need to generate barcode for all elements of number array

```
// Including all required classes
require_once('incl/class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('incl/class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('incl/class/BCGDrawing.php');

// Including the barcode technology
require_once('incl/class/BCGcode39.barcode.php');

// Loading Font
$font = new BCGFontFile('./incl/class/font/Arial.ttf', 18);

// The arguments are R, G, B for color.
$color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

$drawException = null;
try {
    $code = new BCGcode39();
    $code->setScale(2); // Resolution
    $code->setThickness(30); // Thickness
    $code->setForegroundColor($color_black); // Color of bars
    $code->setBackgroundColor($color_white); // Color of spaces
    $code->setFont($font); // Font (or 0)
    $code->parse('1'); // Text
} catch(Exception $exception) {
    $drawException = $exception;
}

/* Here is the list of the arguments
1 - Filename (empty : display on screen)
2 - Background color */
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
if($drawException) {
    $drawing->drawException($drawException);
} else {
    $drawing->setBarcode($code);
    $drawing->draw();
}

// Header that says it is an image (remove it if you save the barcode to a file)
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Draw (or save) the image into PNG format.
$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I've never used the library before, it looks like you would just need to do the following:

```
foreach ($barcodes as $barcode) {
    $code->parse($barcode);
    $drawing->setBarcode($code);
    $drawing->draw();
}
```

where $barcodes is an array containing your barcode numbers and the foreach is in the place of where your current `$drawing->draw();` part is

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can of course extract only 1 part to put in a loop, but I wouldn't recommend it because if something else crashes based on the input, then you won't be able to recover or know what happened.

I would recommend that you write the $code into an array. So new-ing a new BCGcode39 for each of them.

Same thing with the BCGDrawing, it's a drawing surface. You cannot use the same drawing surface for all the barcodes unless you change the position of them.

You probably want to generate multiple files? in order to do so, you need to change the first argument of BCGDrawing.

so basically

```
foreach($barcodes as $basicString) {
    $drawException = null;
    ...
    $code->parse($basicString);
    ...
    $drawing = new BCGDrawing($basicString . '.png', $color_white);
    ...
    $drawing->draw();
    ...
    // NO header()
    $drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
}
```